# What is the solution to this error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I have a Javascript file — I know the code is pretty messy right now, but I’m just coding some basic features and what not, then I will clean up the code. The page has three sections inside of those three individual sections are pictures. The pictures are supposed to change every 30 seconds. What is causing this error?

The error printed to the console: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.images[1].src = images[alternate]’)

Here’s the code:

```
var alternate = 0;
var timerId;
var images = ["img/s1.jpg", "img/tourism.jpg", "img/s2.jpg", "img/shopping.jpg", "img/dining.jpg", "img/shopping2.jpg", "img/s3.jpg"]; // Image URLs in a image array

function startAnimation() {

    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var meridian = "AM";
    var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;

    if (hours < 12 && meridian == "PM" || hours == 0) {
        hours = hours + 12;
        meridian == "AM";
        time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
    } else if (hours > 12 && meridian == "AM") {
        meridian = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
        time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
    }
    //hours < 12 ? meridian : "AM";

    // comment on code here.
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
        time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
    }

    // comment on code here.
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
        time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
    }

    //alternate = (alternate == 0) ? 1 : 0; // Alternate images

    if (alternate == 0) {
        alternate = 3;
    } else {
        alternate = 0;
    }

    if (alternate == 1) {
        alternate = 2;
    } else {
        alternate = 1;
    }

    //document.images[0].src = images[alternate];  // Update image
    document.images[1].src = images[alternate];
    timerId = setTimeout("startAnimation()", 30000); // 30 second update

    if (images[alternate] == images[0]) {
        console.log(time + " " + images[0] + " has been loaded.");
    }

    if (images[alternate] == images[3]) {
        console.log(time + " " + images[3] + " has been loaded.");
    }

    if (images[alternate] != images[0] || images[alternate] != images[3]) {
        console.log("Please wait while the debugging process is in effect.");
    }

}

 startAnimation();
```

Comment: My gut says `document.images[1]` is wrong. Although I'm bad at JS and the DOM IDK what the answer is

Answer (score 1):

Yo have few typos and mistakes:

```
meridian == "AM";
```

has to be `meridian = "AM";`

Also

```
timerId = setTimeout("startAnimation()", 30000);
```

Has to be:

```
setTimeout(startAnimation, 30000);
```

Comment: Passing a string to `setTimeout()` is valid. It's not recommended, but it shouldn't be necessary to change it to get the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. The error has occurred : Wrong setTimeout() implementation and wrong assignment operator that you used.

```js
var alternate = 0;
var timerId;
var images = [
  "img/s1.jpg",
  "img/tourism.jpg",
  "img/s2.jpg",
  "img/shopping.jpg",
  "img/dining.jpg",
  "img/shopping2.jpg",
  "img/s3.jpg"
]; // Image URLs in a image array

function startAnimation() {

  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var meridian = "AM";
  var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;

  if (hours < 12 && meridian == "PM" || hours === 0) {
    hours = hours + 12;
    meridian = "AM";
    time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
  } else if (hours > 12 && meridian == "AM") {
    meridian = "PM";
    hours = hours - 12;
    time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
  }
  //hours < 12 ? meridian : "AM";

  // comment on code here.
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
    time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
  }

  // comment on code here.
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
    time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + meridian;
  }

  //alternate = (alternate == 0) ? 1 : 0; // Alternate images

  if (alternate === 0) {
    alternate = 3;
  } else {
    alternate = 0;
  }

  if (alternate == 1) {
    alternate = 2;
  } else {
    alternate = 1;
  }

  //document.images[0].src = images[alternate];  // Update image
  document.images[0].src = images[alternate];
  timerId = setTimeout(startAnimation(), 30000); // 30 second update

  if (images[alternate] == images[0]) {
    console.log(time + " " + images[0] + " has been loaded.");
  }

  if (images[alternate] == images[3]) {
    console.log(time + " " + images[3] + " has been loaded.");
  }

  if (images[alternate] != images[0] || images[alternate] != images[3]) {
    console.log("Please wait while the debugging process is in effect.");
  }

}

startAnimation();
```

```html
<img src="" alt="">
```

Comment: And what, we have to play "spot the difference"? What was wrong with the original code?

Comment: He was used, `meridian == "AM";` instead of `meridian = "AM";` and invalid `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @ DININDU Thanks for the assistance!